# InvalidAccessKeyId error while running the tests in snowflake-s3compat-api-test-suite

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to the run the tests against my localhost server using the following command: `mvn test -Dtest=S3CompatApiTest` but I'm seeing an error: https://pastecode.io/s/099599z3

It shows the following error:

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: InvalidAccessKeyId
> (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId;
> Request ID: tx0000004c652335d642249-0065f2ca25-4143-default; S3
> Extended Request ID: 4143-default-default; Proxy: null)   at
> com.snowflake.s3compatapitestsuite.compatapi.S3CompatApiTest.uploadAnObjectToTestingLocation(S3CompatApiTest.java:424)
> at
> com.snowflake.s3compatapitestsuite.compatapi.S3CompatApiTest.copyObject(S3CompatApiTest.java:360)

P.S: I'm following the documented steps with setting the environment variables as well but still it fails with this error.

Can someone help me figure out the point of failure or something that I'm missing out?

All the steps as mentioned in the documentation

Comment: Hi - please don’t link to external sites. Add all relevant information directly to your question as editable text

Comment: It shows the following error: `com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: InvalidAccessKeyId (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId; Request ID: tx0000004c652335d642249-0065f2ca25-4143-default; S3 Extended Request ID: 4143-default-default; Proxy: null)
 at com.snowflake.s3compatapitestsuite.compatapi.S3CompatApiTest.uploadAnObjectToTestingLocation(S3CompatApiTest.java:424)
 at com.snowflake.s3compatapitestsuite.compatapi.S3CompatApiTest.copyObject(S3CompatApiTest.java:360)`